# Split , filter and summarize dataset by country and the clostes smaller year

Tags: r

I have a dataset which 5326 obs and 33 variables:
the first 15 variables are country name, country code, year of observation, and other data
the variables 15 to 33 are the data that i have to use.
this data are some performance by country by year by a specific political party.
My aim is:
take a year->for every country use the data with the closest smaller year,and for every variables summarize it by avery country.
so the  outcome will be a matrix with first column as a country name, second as a year , and the other 17 the sum of the variables by country.
so how can i approach this problem?
if further information is needed pls fell free to ask me, thanks

```
> str(party.osp5)
tibble [5,326 x 33] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ paenname     : chr [1:5326] "Party of the Democratic Revolution" "Party of the Democratic Revolution" "Party of the Democratic Revolution" "Party of the Democratic Revolution" ...
 $ pashname     : chr [1:5326] "PRD" "PRD" "PRD" "PRD" ...
 $ pf_party_id    : num [1:5326] 216 216 216 216 216 216 216 216 216 216 ...
 $ country_name   : chr [1:5326] "Mexico" "Mexico" "Mexico" "Mexico" ...
 $ country_id     : num [1:5326] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ country_text_id: chr [1:5326] "MEX" "MEX" "MEX" "MEX" ...
 $ year           : num [1:5326] 1991 1994 1997 2000 2003 ...
 $ codingstart    : num [1:5326] 1940 1940 1940 1940 1940 1940 1940 1940 1940 1940 ...
 $ codingend      : num [1:5326] 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
 $ project        : num [1:5326] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ COWcode        : num [1:5326] 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
 $ e_regiongeo    : num [1:5326] 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 ...
 $ e_regionpol    : num [1:5326] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ e_regionpol_6C : num [1:5326] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ paseatshare  : num [1:5326] 8.2 14.2 25 13 19.4 25.2 14.2 20.8 11.2 4.2 ...
 $ illiberal: num [1:5326] 1.93 2.93 4.35 2.76 5.18 ...
 $ popul    : num [1:5326] 6.22 10.62 17.3 9.11 13.6 ...
 $ papariah_osp : num [1:5326] 19.4 36.4 65 34.8 50.2 ...
 $ paanteli_osp : num [1:5326] 26.5 44.7 68.3 36.6 53.5 ...
 $ papeople_osp : num [1:5326] 23.6 40.9 70.7 36.8 56 ...
 $ paopresp_osp : num [1:5326] 12.8 23.4 45.5 24.9 33.1 ...
 $ paplur_osp   : num [1:5326] 28.3 48.4 87.9 44.3 63.5 ...
 $ paminor_osp  : num [1:5326] 22.3 39.4 69.4 36.1 51 ...
 $ paviol_osp   : num [1:5326] 29.4 53.5 94.2 47.9 71.8 ...
 $ paimmig_osp  : num [1:5326] 21 36.4 64.1 34.4 51.3 ...
 $ palgbt_osp   : num [1:5326] 22.2 39.1 70.3 38.5 55.7 ...
 $ paculsup_osp : num [1:5326] 22 38.1 67 34.8 46.7 ...
 $ parelig_osp  : num [1:5326] 30.9 53.6 94.3 49 73.2 ...
 $ pagender_osp : num [1:5326] 16 27.7 55.4 37.7 54 ...
 $ pawomlab_osp : num [1:5326] 25.7 45.6 80.2 43.1 64.4 ...
 $ pariglef_osp : num [1:5326] 13.6 23.5 41.3 21.5 32.1 ...
 $ pawelf_osp   : num [1:5326] 32.8 56.7 99.9 51.9 75.3 ...
 $ paclient_osp : num [1:5326] 17.4 30.1 63.6 35.9 56.4 ...
```

the outcome of dput(head(df))is:

```
dput(head(party.osp5))
structure(list(v2paenname = c("Party of the Democratic Revolution", 
"Party of the Democratic Revolution", "Party of the Democratic Revolution", 
"Party of the Democratic Revolution", "Party of the Democratic Revolution", 
"Party of the Democratic Revolution"), v2pashname = c("PRD", 
"PRD", "PRD", "PRD", "PRD", "PRD"), pf_party_id = c(216, 216, 
216, 216, 216, 216), country_name = c("Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", 
"Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico"), country_id = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3), country_text_id = c("MEX", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX", "MEX"
), year = c(1991, 1994, 1997, 2000, 2003, 2006), codingstart = c(1940, 
1940, 1940, 1940, 1940, 1940), codingend = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018), project = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), COWcode = c(70, 
70, 70, 70, 70, 70), e_regiongeo = c(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17), 
    e_regionpol = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), e_regionpol_6C = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2), v2paseatshare = c(8.2, 14.2, 25, 13, 19.4, 
    25.2), v2xpa_illiberal = c(1.927, 2.9252, 4.35, 2.756, 5.1798, 
    9.3996), v2xpa_popul = c(6.2238, 10.6216, 17.3, 9.113, 13.5994, 
    20.7396), v2papariah_osp = c(19.4094, 36.3662, 65, 34.762, 
    50.246, 67.8888), v2paanteli_osp = c(26.5352, 44.7442, 68.35, 
    36.556, 53.4858, 80.8416), v2papeople_osp = c(23.6078, 40.8818, 
    70.7, 36.764, 56.0272, 86.184), v2paopresp_osp = c(12.8494, 
    23.3732, 45.45, 24.895, 33.1352, 31.4748), v2paplur_osp = c(28.2572, 
    48.3794, 87.875, 44.304, 63.4768, 80.2116), v2paminor_osp = c(22.3204, 
    39.4334, 69.425, 36.101, 51.0414, 59.9508), v2paviol_osp = c(29.3888, 
    53.4772, 94.15, 47.892, 71.8382, 87.57), v2paimmig_osp = c(21.0166, 
    36.3946, 64.075, 34.372, 51.2936, 65.4696), v2palgbt_osp = c(22.1564, 
    39.1352, 70.325, 38.48, 55.6974, 77.0112), v2paculsup_osp = c(21.976, 
    38.056, 67, 34.84, 46.6764, 60.6312), v2parelig_osp = c(30.9386, 
    53.5766, 94.325, 49.049, 73.1962, 95.0796), v2pagender_osp = c(15.9982, 
    27.7042, 55.425, 37.713, 53.9708, 65.9736), v2pawomlab_osp = c(25.7398, 
    45.5536, 80.2, 43.147, 64.3886, 86.1336), v2pariglef_osp = c(13.5546, 
    23.4726, 41.325, 21.489, 32.0682, 39.7908), v2pawelf_osp = c(32.7508, 
    56.7148, 99.85, 51.922, 75.2526, 97.7508), v2paclient_osp = c(17.3758, 
    30.0898, 63.575, 35.893, 56.4152, 73.2816)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to `arrange` by year then `summarize` using `lag`. Look up those function from `dplyr` (a package).

Comment: by now i'm trying with this: `test<- party.osp5 %>% 
  group_by(country_name) %>% 
  mutate(keep.delete = 
           ifelse(H - year == min(H - year), 'keep', 'delete'))`

data<-test[test$keep.delete == "keep",]   but i can only find the closest year, i would like to use the clostse smaller, how con i adjust?

Comment: pls attach a sample of your data using dput()

Comment: i cant do it because is a huge dataset

Comment: Use either `dput(head(df))` or take the trouble of constructing a fake dataframe that reflects the **problem** you want to solve

Comment: i edit the question with the dput outcome